# Combining Arrays with 2 dimensions

Tags: java

I need a little with aligning my arrays. Would I need more Vectors and then do an add row. My first column are checkboxes.

Row 0 should be L that have array1
Row 1 should R that have array2
Row3 should be S that have array3

```
        String array1[] = { dateString1, "10:18:17 PM"};
        String array2[] = {"08:09:110 AM", "10:00:33 AM"};
        String array3[] = {"09:00:561 PM", "07:12:19 AM"};
        String array4[] = { dateString1, "10:18:17 PM"};
        String array5[] = {"08:09:101 AM", "10:00:33 AM"};
        String array6[] = {"09:00:561 PM", "07:12:19 AM"};
        String array7[] = { dateString1, "10:18:17 PM"};
        String array8[] = {"08:09:1011 AM", "10:00:33 AM"};


        String[] p = {"L", "S", "R", "T", "D", "C", "L", "R"};

        boolean[] t3;
```

Desire output:

```
L   dateString1 10:18:17 PM
S   08:09:110 AM    10:00:33 AM
R   09:00:561 PM    7:12:19 AM
```

so on…

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suggest the following :

```
public String[] returnArray(int num){
switch(num)
  case 1 : return array1;
  case 2 : return array2;
  .
  .
  .
  case 8 : return array8;
  default : return null //this shouldn't really happen but its required to return something.
}

public void printArray(){
   for(int i=0;i<p.length;i++){
      System.out.print(p[i] + " " );
      for(String s : returnArray(i+1)) System.out.print(s + " ");
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want it to show in a table using a vector. I have my vectors set up correctly. I just dont how to align up my values correctly

Comment: @Roddrick what do you mean using vector? do you mean u want to use **java.util.vector**? Aligning up values is a matter of printing. just print stuff in appropriate places

Comment: Yes, I want to use vectors, but instead of adding a row, I want to put everything in the next column, so on ....

Comment: @Roddrick your given source codes doesn't show any sign of using vectors. beside, I don't understand how vectors can be used in this case. if you really want to put them in a vector then use my code instead of printing the Strings, just add them to a vector